# What, if anything, does "Spark plugs starting to blow through" mean?

Tags: sparkplugs, diagnose

I just took my old car (2004 Toyota Wish - 1.8 litre petrol engine, 185000km) to a mechanic for a basic service and warrant of fitness.  The vehicle passed the warrant, but I was advised "spark plugs starting to blow through".  (This is stated on the invoice description as well)

I googled the term and was surprised to come up with no results. Does anyone know what, if anything this term means?   If so, would simply replacing the spark plugs fix the problem, or is it potentially more expensive then that?

Comment: Maybe they meant the spark was arcing out. Open hood and watch the plugs/packs while engines running in the dark and see if you notice any blue flashing.

Comment: Ask the mechanic what, exactly, they meant, that is your best option compared to you, or us, just guessing.

Comment: @SolarMike thank you - based on your answers I'm gaining some confidence that what he has said is not using standard terms.

Comment: Its a nonsense term used to impress you. I would ask the mechanic that used that term what it means specifically, see if you can get some more nonsense jargon out of them.